# Nested exceptions for menu handling?

Tags: python, exception, nested

I succeeded building a nice menu in python with exceptions:

```
class InputError(Exception): pass
class DigitalIoTest(Exception): pass
class MotorEnableTest(Exception): pass

while True:
        print("[1] Digital I/O Test")
        print("[2] Motor Enable Test")
        key = input("Please select test:")

        try: 
            if key == '1': raise DigitalIoTest
            elif key == '2': raise MotorEnableTest
            else: raise InputError

        except InputError:
            print("Input error!")

        except DigitalIoTest:
            pass
    
        except MotorEnableTest:
            pass
```

Now I need to add another menu item [3] which executes **all** tests in the menu. This is what I tried so far:

```
class InputError(Exception): pass
class DigitalIoTest(Exception): pass
class MotorEnableTest(Exception): pass
class AllTests: pass

while True:
        print("[1] Digital I/O Test")
        print("[2] Motor Enable Test")
        print("[3] All Tests")
        key = input("Please select test:")

        try: 
            if key == '1': raise DigitalIoTest
            elif key == '2': raise MotorEnableTest
            elif key == '3': raise AllTests
            else: raise InputError

        except InputError:
            print("Input error!")

        except DigitalIoTest:
            pass
    
        except MotorEnableTest:
            pass

        except AllTests:
            try:  
                raise DigitalIoTest
                raise MotorEnableTest
            except: 
                pass
```

This does not work as intended. Can someone give me a hint how I can achieve such a nested exception to execute all tests serially?

Comment: Wait, what? Why are you using exceptions for this?

Comment: Because I do not know how to do this another way that is so simple and elegant (I mean little code and good structure).

Comment: But... even ignoring the intended usage of exceptions, this is an extra layer of try-except handling around an elif chain that could have handled everything on its own. It's more complex than if you hadn't brought exceptions into the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using exceptions to indicate what the normal flow of the program should be doing, which is not really the use intended for exceptions. How about writing it like so:

```
while True:
        print("[1] Digital I/O Test")
        print("[2] Motor Enable Test")
        print("[3] All Tests")
        key = input("Please select test:")

        
        if key == '1': 
            do_what_you_need_for_1()
        elif key == '2': 
            do_what_you_need_for_2()
        elif key == '3': 
            do_what_you_need_for_3()
        else: raise InputError
```

If you need to call more than a single function, then call more than a single function. Reserve the exceptions for things that are exceptions (like the input error).

Comment: Thanks, that would work. But if I still would prefer the "exceptional" way, is there a solution for this?

Comment: I miss the "goto label" instruction from the old days of programming :-)

Comment: @StefanWyss The use of goto is long known to be problematic, and there are reasons to avoid using exceptions for normal flows. Python, in particular, emphasizes readability. It might be a good opportunity to code according to the principles of the language - among other things, others will find your code more readable and not perplexing.

Comment: You convinced me. I will use the functional menu approach. Thanks!